# Sails.js: Best practice for calculating a model's attribute on api create?

Tags: sails.js

Assuming I had the following model, what is the best practice in Sails.js to calculate the `sum` attribute from one or more non-persistent attributes on the create API call?

In this example I want to extend the default create behaviour of this models API's to accept the additional attributes `valueOne` and `valueTwo`, and then calculate the `sum` attribute based on a simple `valueOne + valueTwo` calculation.

Ideally without losing the out of the box validation on other fields on the model, e.g `name`, but not requiring `sum` to be submitted at the API level, while still being required on the model itself.

**api/models/CalculatedData.js**

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    name: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },


    sum: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true
    }

  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could do this.

If there is only one controller where you populate this model, then you could calculate the sum in your controller and pass the result to the model create method.

Or you could have a service that does that for you. Though a better way would be to have a custom model method that populates the model.

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        // your attributes
    },

    customCreate: function (options, cb) {
        options.sum = options.values.reduce(function (a, b) {
            return a + b;
        });

        delete options.values;
        Model.create(options).exec(cb);
    }
};
```

#### Edit

A better way is to use a `beforeCreate` [life-cycle callback](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/lifecycle-callbacks)

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        // your attributes
    },

    beforeCreate: function (options, cb) {
        options.sum = options.values.reduce(function (a, b) {
            return a + b;
        });

        delete options.values;
        return cb();
    }
};
```

Comment: Assuming I used the code snippet you've provided in your answer, how would I go about calling that from the create API endpoint (generated by sails), instead of the default create method on the model?

Comment: Humm, you could override the blueprint create method, but that would override it for all models. A better way is probably using the beforeCreate lifecycle callback